# List of primary key components

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, primary-key

I am making a list from a database where I want to show the number of columns that make up the primary key in each particular table in SQL Server.

For example, if Table A has a single column as primary key, Table B has a compound key of 3 parts, and Table C has a compound key of 2 parts, the result would be:

```
Table Name   No. PK Components
----------   -----------------
Table A             1 
Table B             3
Table C             2
```

I have tried many times using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `sys` but failed.

Comment: Tables can have no more than one primary key. Can you clarify what it is that you're looking for? Tables w/o a PK at all? The number of columns in each tables PK? Other?

Comment: Table A has only 1 primary key. Table B have 2 primary key (composite key) Table C have 3 primary key (composite key) Therefore result will show Table A  1 Table B  3 Table C 2.

As you said, it is, I mean I need number of columns are PK in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking just how many columns are part of PK, this could solve your problem:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME , COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) No_PK_Cols
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + CONSTRAINT_NAME), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchema'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks. But in your answer need  group by TABLE_NAME

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it really helps me much